# How to unzip CAB file with ActiveX on unix system?

Tags: unix, cab

I tried to use unzip, bunzip2, gunzip.
But none of these tools can unzip CAB file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what ActiveX has to do with it but you can try: [cabextract](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/)

Comment: @Vladimir Bezugliy, In my experience the standard unix tools usually give you everything you need to compile it from source.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in tool to handle CAB; it's not a standard or Unix file format. As Mike said, you'll probably need `cabextract`. There are [some packages](http://bio.gsi.de/DOCS/AIX/aixpdslib.seas.ucla.edu/packages) that might be of use depending on what version of AIX you are running.

Otherwise you will need to compile it. If you don't have the AIX compiler, you'll have to [install GCC](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Gcc).

(What a sad and user-hostile place Old Unix was before Linux; it's pretty damned pathetic if compilers are still paid extras.)